# How to drill through report work under PowerBI App

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We are currently facing an issue where the drill-through functionality is not functioning as expected within the Power BI app. However, it's same drill-through report works as intended within the Power BI workspace. Does anyone have insights into how drill-through operates specifically within the Power BI app?